# Tadpole VEV from a fermion loop?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, feynman-diagrams, higgs, beyond-the-standard-model

We have one extra complex scalar $\Phi$ beyond the Standard Model (BSM) protected by an $U(1)$ global symmetry, which is broken by an Yukawa coupling $ y_\Phi \Phi \overline{\chi} \chi$, where $\chi$ is a new BSM fermion.

Will $\Phi$ achieve a tadpole vev from the tadpole diagram with a $\chi$-loop due to the new Yukawa coupling?

Comment: Hi Rosenlyst. Welcome to Phys.SE. Consider to include the Feynman diagram for clarity.